# Import csv files containing data with commas into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, wamp, wampserver, mysql-python

I have more than 10GB .csv files. I m trying to import the data from these files into MySQL using python. Since csv files are comma separated files, and I have data which itself contains commas, therefore I can not use ',' here for splitting. There please suggest some other option
for splitting the csv file.
I want to import the data from the csv file(where the data itself contains comma) to MySQL (i am using Wamp server for the same).
I have data like 'london, u.k.', '2010', 'credit, saving'

Comment: maybe if you provide example of the data we can think of something.

Comment: i have provided the example data in the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I am assuming that the CSV files have quotes around the string values.

Thus each value containing a comma is surrounded by a quote like this:

> a, b, 2, 'foo, bar'

If so, then you can use the following:

import

```
 csv

quoteChar = "'"

myReader = csv.reader(open('largefile.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quoteChar = quoteChar)

for row in myReader:
    print row # this prints a list. Row is a list of values per line in your
    # 'largefile.csv' file. Each row is splitted on the delimiter char.
    # (comma in this case) and strings that are quoted by quoteChar (in your case
    # a ' are treated differently.) This will work for your input that you've given
    # in your question.

# this is what you used to do:
for line in open('largefile.csv', 'rb'):
     row = line.split(quoteChar)
```

If otherwise it'll depend on how your CSV files look like.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I also have to transfer this content to MySQL database, therefore I was doing the following: for row in myReader: values=row.split(',') and then storing these values into MySQL. This split is essentially causing the problem. Is there an alternative way of transferring data into MySQL

Comment: @user869790: Daan is showing you how an alternative way. Python's built-in `csv` module is what you should be using for this task. Don't reinvent what's already been built and tested for you.

Comment: @user869790 Adam Bernier is right. I've updated my answer to clarify things a bit more. the row from in myReader is the same (type) of 'row' that you'll get after line.split() but then 'better'. The CSV module does all of this for you. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @AdamBernier Just a naive question, please forgive me since I am a novice. How do i check to know the kind of csv file i have. Since i ran the above code and found my data is not surrounded by double quotes, also I am able to view the file in 'xlsx'

Comment: @DaanTimmer Thanks your approach too worked. Really appreciate your help

Comment: @AdamBernier Thanks for the help the approach worked. Really appreciate your help

Comment: @user869790 no problem. The other solution is more elegant and probably faster. Mine is more python-related (because you too were having problems with parsing a CSV data). Glad to have been of help :-)

Answer (score 6):

A good answer has been provided for importing using Python. But I'm unclear as to why you need Python to do it. MySQL has built-in commands for importing CSV data---see the [load data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) manual page. For example,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'source_data.csv'
INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

That last part ignores the first line (use if your CSV file has a "header").

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping. But since I am a novice, i don't know whether my csv file(which i am viewing in xls) is enclosed by quotes, also my data has comments, so I think there must be quotes in it, the data is just like stackoverflows data, which i converted to csv for storing into database. Can u please give me a clue so that i may check the enclosing symbol. Thanks again for helping

Comment: @user869790, well, the "optionally" part indicates that there doesn't always have do be double-quotes around the field. If you want to see what encloses your fields, you could open the file and look through the data before running the `LOAD` command on it.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Is there a good way by which I can only enter records pertaining to some years and not all years as are there in the dataset

Comment: Using this approach, not directly. I would recommend loading it all into a single table that you plan to throw away, and then use `CREATE TABLE .. SELECT` syntax to generate the table with the data you actually want. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqlimport

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=, --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' --verbose --local -u root -p DB_Name csv/path.csv > save_log.log
```